# Java syntax error buffered reader

Tags: java, bufferedreader

I'm writing a class that just reads a text file and prints out the lines.  I'm getting an error on the line containing BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("file.txt")); saying that Syntax error on token ";", { expected after this token.  I've tried placing it within a method, and within a try catch block as it recommends but then I'm unable to resolve the rd variable.  I'm using the acm package so some of the other syntax may look different but I receive no other errors.  Any help would be greatly appreciated =)

```
import acm.program.*;
import acm.util.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class FileReading extends ConsoleProgram {   

BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("file.txt"));

try {
    while (true) {          
        String line = rd.readLine();
        if (line == null) {
            break;
        }
        println(line);
    }
    rd.close();
}
catch (IOException ex) {
    throw new ErrorException(ex);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: You have to put that code inside a method!..

Comment: @Jarod: It is possible if you make `rd` static variable, but it may goes against the design if `rd` is supposed to be a separate `Reader` for every `FileReading` object created.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Code blocks like this should be embodied inside a method or a static clause. Something like:

```
public class FileReading extends ConsoleProgram {   

   public void readFile(){
     BufferedReader rd = null;
     try {
         rd = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("file.txt"));
         while (true) {          
            String line = rd.readLine();
            if (line == null) {
                break;
            }
            println(line);
         }
     }catch (IOException ex) {
         throw new ErrorException(ex);
     }finally{
        try{
         rd.close();
        }catch (IOException ex) {
         throw new ErrorException(ex);
        }
     }
   }
}
```

Comment: I had tried this earlier, but I still receive this error when I do it: Unhandled exception type FileNotFoundException pertaining to new FileReader("file.txt") in which it recommends to add throws declaration or surround with try/catch.  The try/catch leaves rd undefined below, and adding this: public void readFile() throws FileNotFoundException { will run it but it produces a blank output.  I have checked that the file is in the project folder, named correctly, and that it has text to display.

Comment: Looks like your application can not find the file. Have you tried providing the full path to your file?

Comment: And see my edit for an improved answer (as to the try catch scope error)

Comment: I'm not quite sure how to add that, I just tried BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\users\username\workspace\projectname\file.txt"));  and received Invalid unicode.

Comment: Ah thank you for that code that resolves all the compiling errors.  I am getting a blank output still and I tried a second file, making sure it wasn't blank as well.

Comment: Actually the problem has been resolved.  I had forgotten that I had to rename the method name to something else in use with the acm package.  It's working now, thanks so much for your help =)

Answer (score 1):

As answered by others, you cant provide your code in the general part of the class, it has to be within a method or static block.

By putting the code block in the constructor the problem went away.
See below for example.

```
import acm.program.*;
import acm.util.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class FileReading extends ConsoleProgram {   
public FileReading()
{
BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("file.txt"));

try {
    while (true) {          
        String line = rd.readLine();
        if (line == null) {
            break;
        }
        println(line);
    }
    rd.close();
}
catch (IOException ex) {
    throw new ErrorException(ex);
    }
}
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Create a method... and inside that do this... Not directly inside the class**

eg:

```
public void go()
{

    BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("file.txt"));

try {
    while (true) {          
        String line = rd.readLine();
        if (line == null) {
            break;
        }
        println(line);
    }
    rd.close();
}
catch (IOException ex) {
    throw new ErrorException(ex);
    }
}

}
```